# How can I have the equivalent of django's admin inlines in a modelform?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

Django's admin allows you to easily create a form for editing a model and its foreign keys, but if I'm using a ModelForm in my own view, I'm having trouble accomplishing this. Here's an example in admin.py:

```
class VendorPhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = VendorPhoto
  extra = 3

class VendorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [VendorPhotoInline]

admin.site.register(Vendor, VendorAdmin)
```

So now in the admin, I can create a Vendor and add a bunch of photos. However for non-staff, I have a form for creating a Vendor, and I'd like to allow them to upload some photos like the admin.

I'm using a ModelForm that allows users to create new Vendors, but of course, they can't add photos at this point:

```
class VendorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
```

How can I achieve parity with the admin interface here? I'd settle for a solution that just works for new Vendor instances and allows uploading of up to a certain number (say, 3), but something that works for existing instances and allows adding / deleting photos would be great too. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). From the documentation:

Suppose you have these two models:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

If you want to create a formset that allows you to edit books
belonging to a particular author, you could do this:

```
>>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
>>> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
>>> author = Author.objects.get(name=u'Mike Royko')
>>> formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
```

The `inlineformset_factory` takes care of things behind the scenes, but for the front-end part you may find the [django-dynamic-formset jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) useful.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the documentation, though it just creates a formset for the Books. I probably just lack a good understanding of Django forms, but I'm unclear on how to have a formset for a new Author in the same view and template <form> and have the new inline Books associated with the newly created Author. I want a view/template that does what the /add URL would do for the admin of my example, allowing to create a new Vendor and some associated VendorPhotos in one <form>.

Comment: @mrooney, I think the only insight you're missing is that you can have multiple Django forms in the same HTML `<form>`. You pass both the `ModelForm` for the parent model and the formset to the template and then process them in the view.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I found http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/ which has some helpful view code and also demonstrates how to validate all forms before saving the parent instance.